# I couldn't understand the getters

Tags: javascript, getter

I dont understand the function of getters. For example what's the difference between I use getter or directly write the key of property named 'language' at the images at images below?

[Code with getter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BArAS.png)

[Code without getter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5hNe.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters getters and setters are so you are not setting and retrieving data directly.

Comment: Getters make sense if the do something other than returning a simple value. E.g. you can have a code that always retrieves the data from the server. Or validates if the user is allowed to get the value. Or count how many times the value has been read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using getters you are able to modify the output. You cant do this if you only read the property itself. Imagine you would have method to get a name out of a property. You could use the getter to capitalize the first char.